# Purpose of type void declared in java generics

Tags: java, android

I was going through [vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask1) and i can across this:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

I am not sure what this void means and why is it being used ?

Comment: Read through generics and the javadoc of `Void`. `The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void`

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the documentation of [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:
>
> - *Params*, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
> - *Progress*, the type of the progress units published during the
>     background computation.
> - *Result*, the type of the result of the
>     background computation.
>
> Not all types are always used by an
>   asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type `Void`:
>
> ```
> private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
> ```

[`Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) is just a type argument, similar to how you give `Integer`, `Float`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter goes into `onProgressUpdate()`. In case you do not want to make progress update notifications you pass `Void` as the second parameter and do not implement `onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 1):

Void used there means that you are not going to publish results before async task finish.

Answer (score 0):

See AsyncTask javadoc :

> Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type
>   as unused, simply use the type `Void`:
>
> `private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }`

Void in generics simply means that your parameterised class will use void wherever this generic is used (generally for return value).